# Unable to detect Wifi signals

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

Recently my old wifi adapter broke, so I had to buy a new one. Eventually I got around to it but it doesn't seem to work. I have bought one from TP-LINK, returned it for the same issue as I'm having now, got a new one, same problem. Now I have a D-Link DWA-140, and nothing has changed.

I have tried, to my knowlage, everything. With all three adapters I've installed the drivers manually from the manufacturer's website. Googled for hours. I've looked everywhere in my PC but I can't find the problem anywhere. I am now running an Ethernet cable trough the house to be able to connect to the internet. This, however, does tell me that there is nothing wrong with the internet connection. Mobile devices and other PCs and laptops don't seem to have any issues, just my PC.

I am running Windows 7, the adapter is a D-Link DWA-140, my router is a Sitecom Mimo XR.

I hope someone knows what's up.

Thanks in advance

[FIXED] Appereantly, Avast! installed a firewall driver plug-in along with the actual driver for the adapter. Once disabled, it workes like a charm.

Comment: "unable to detect Wifi signals", "It doesn't work" and "the same issues" doesn't tell us much. What _exactly_ is the problem you're experiencing?  Have you tried a fresh Windows install or a 3rd party OS (Linux LiveCD for example) yet?

Comment: That's just it.. i do not know the exact problem. all I can see is that windows tells me the device is working properly but the wifi icon shows me the wifi bars with a red cross through them. When I troubleshoot the connection problem through Windows, it tells me this: "There might be a problem with the driver for the Wireless Network Connection 5 adapter. A network cable is not properly plugged in or may be broken" This is the same error it gave me with the other brand new adapters. i've tried other usb ports aswell, same issue.

Comment: I just installed Unbuntu as a secondary operating system to be able to try the install on another OS. But when I plug in the device, I can't seem to find it anywhere in Unbuntu. The installation CD from the device doesn't seem to want to run on Unbuntu, I can't start the autorun... I'm running out of ideas here

Comment: (Update) I looked on the D-Link site, they don't have drivers for linux. So I dont think that would work anyway